# Problema al usar EF6 c# error de clase

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hola soy nuevo en c# estoy intentando usar EF6 pero a la hora de insertar me da este error que adjunto en la imagen
[image: Ver Imagen]

```
namespace sng01
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("sngpos.Cliente")]
public partial class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int cedula { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    public int tipo { get; set; }

    public int estado { get; set; }
}
}

namespace sng01
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class sng_db : DbContext
{
    public sng_db()
        : base("name=sng_dbcon")
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>()
            .Property(e => e.nombre)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}

}


 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using(var demo = new sng_db())
        {
            Cliente cli = new Cliente() { nombre = "DiegoSNG" };
            demo.Cliente.Add(cli);
            demo.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: coloca tu código, la imagen sola genera información muy limitada. https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> revisa a detalle por favor. Bienvenido a bordo :D saludos

Comment: mira en tu clase "sng_db", compara:
base("name=sng_dbcon") y 
base(nameOrConnectionString: "MonkeyFist")

Comment: Si amigo eso ya lo compare y lo hice igual no entiendo aun lo que me dice que estoy infringiendo las reglas de seguridad o la accesibilidad de la clase

Answer (score 1):

El ejmplo a continuación estará en un proyecto de consola, debemos tener una base de datos y una tabla con datos

Vamos por partes, necesitamos lo siguiente:

1. MySQL Connector/Net 6.8.x
2. MySQL Server 5.1 or above
3. Entity Framework 6 assemblies
4. .NET Framework 4.0 or above

Instalamos Entity Framework (EF) desde la consola de NuGet

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Ahora instalamos la compabilidad de EF con MySQL

```
Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity.EF6
```

En nuestro app.config definimos nuestra cadena de conexión

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MonkeyFist" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=user;password=mypass;database=mydb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

El App config debería ser algo así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MonkeyFist" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;password=mypass;database=mydb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

La entidad que vamos a usar

```
[Table("customer")]
public class Customer
{
  [Key]
  [Column("id_customer")]
  public int id { get; set; }

  public string customer { get; set; }

  public string nit { get; set; }

  public string address { get; set; }
}
```

El contexto

```
public partial class db_Entities : DbContext
{
  public db_Entities() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "MonkeyFist") { }

  public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

El Main

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    using (var context = new db_Entities())
    {
      var customers = context.Customer.ToList();
      foreach (var cust in customers)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(cust.id + " " + cust.customer + " " + cust.address);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencia: http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/11/18/EntityFramework-MySql/

Comment: Si ya hice ese ejemplo y me arroja el mismo resultado

Comment: coloca tu código para analizarlo :D

Comment: tu código en tu pregunta, así tenemos el sitio ordenado

Comment: Ya lo agregue a mi post original